# setting color range in matplotlib patchcollection

Tags: python, matplotlib, patch

I am plotting a [`PatchCollection`](http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PatchCollection) in matplotlib with coords and patch color values read in from a file.

The problem is that matplotlib seems to automatically scale the color range to the min/max of the data values. How can I manually set the color range? E.g. if my data range is 10-30, but I want to scale this to a color range of 5-50 (e.g. to compare to another plot), how can I do this?

My plotting commands look much the same as in the api example code: [patch_collection.py](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/patch_collection.html)

```
colors = 100 * pylab.rand(len(patches))
p = PatchCollection(patches, cmap=matplotlib.cm.jet, alpha=0.4)
p.set_array(pylab.array(colors))
ax.add_collection(p)
pylab.colorbar(p)

pylab.show()
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use `p.set_clim([5, 50])` to set the color scaling minimums and maximums in the case of your example. Anything in matplotlib that has a colormap has the `get_clim` and [`set_clim`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/cm_api.html#matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable.set_clim) methods.

As a full example:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
import numpy as np

# (modified from one of the matplotlib gallery examples)
resolution = 50 # the number of vertices
N = 100
x       = np.random.random(N)
y       = np.random.random(N)
radii   = 0.1*np.random.random(N)
patches = []
for x1, y1, r in zip(x, y, radii):
    circle = Circle((x1, y1), r)
    patches.append(circle)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

colors = 100*np.random.random(N)
p = PatchCollection(patches, cmap=matplotlib.cm.jet, alpha=0.4)
p.set_array(colors)
ax.add_collection(p)
fig.colorbar(p)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Now, if we just add `p.set_clim([5, 50])` (where `p` is the patch collection) somewhere before we call `fig.show(...)`, we get this:
[image]