# Python: plot disks of exact radii

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib

I have tho following issue: i have two Numpy arrays containing the `x`,`y` coordinates of many (potentiality, tens of thousand) of disks, whose (different) radii are contained in a third array `r`. Both the radii and the coordinates are measured with the same units. I would like to plot them with the exact radius given by `r` but in a fast way.

I have found some partial solutions (Matplotlib `scatter` can use the three arrays and it is reasonably fast, but the size is scale in points, the `Circles` instances are too slow and `Mayavi` is in my opinion an overkill since the problem is 2d).

The speed is important due to the large number of circles I want to plot. Is there a simple native solution that did not come to my mind?

Comment: Did you try using a collection in matplotlib this is usually much faster.  See for example in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028675/setting-color-range-in-matplotlib-patchcollection

Comment: It is not bad, thank you. But isn't the for loop a problem when I want thousands of disks to be plotted?

Comment: The for loop creates  a list of patches which are than used to create the collection object by itself i think, so the ploting should be faster.  I once had a problem where I had to plot like thousend of lines and using a LineCollection made it much faster.