# How to cycle colors in Matplotlib PatchCollection?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to automatically give each `Patch` in a `PatchCollection` a color from a color map like `tab20`.

```
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
coords = [
    (0, 0),
    (1, 2),
    (1, 3),
    (2, 2),
]
patches = [plt.Circle(coords[i], 0.1) for i in range(len(coords))]
patch_collection = PatchCollection(patches, cmap='tab20', match_original=True)
ax.add_collection(patch_collection)

ax.set_xlim(-1, 3)
ax.set_ylim(-1, 4)
plt.axis('equal')
```

But the above code is drawing each circle using the same color. How can the colors be cycled?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Here I've *sampled* the `tab20` colormap, so that the RGBA array `cmap.colors` has exactly 20 different entries, then I've assigned this RGBA array to the keyword argument `facecolors` that every collection accepts.

Not just for cosmetics, I've added a colormap, so that it's possible to recognize the order in which the circles were drawn.

```
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import rand, seed

seed(20230104)
N = 20
coords = rand(N,2)*[2,1.2]
cmap = plt.get_cmap('tab20', N)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
patches = [plt.Circle(coord, 0.06) for coord in coords]
# use facecolors=...
collection = PatchCollection(patches, facecolors=cmap.colors[:N-1])
ax.add_collection(collection)
cb = plt.colorbar(plt.cm.ScalarMappable(plt.Normalize(-0.5, N-0.5), cmap))
cb.set_ticks(range(N), labels=('%02d'%(n+1) for n in range(N)))
ax.autoscale(collection)
ax.set_aspect(1)
```

---

<sup>*Overdone Version*</sup>

[image]

```
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import rand, seed

seed(20230104)
N = 20
coords = rand(N, 2) * [2, 1.2]
cmap = plt.get_cmap("tab20", N)
patches = (plt.Circle(coord, 0.06) for coord in coords)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.add_collection(
    PatchCollection(
        patches,
        facecolors=cmap.colors,
        edgecolors="w",
        linewidth=2,
        cmap=cmap,
        norm=plt.Normalize(-0.50, N - 0.50),
    )
)

cb = plt.colorbar(
    im,
    location="bottom",
    fraction=0.05,
    aspect=50,
    drawedges=True,
)
cb.set_ticks(range(N), labels=("%02d" % (n + 1) for n in range(N)))
cb.dividers.set_color(ax._facecolor)
cb.dividers.set_linewidth(3)

ax.autoscale()
ax.set_aspect(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives each patch its color from a fixed subset of colors in the selected colormap, repeating as necessary:

```
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num_col = 3
cmap = plt.cm.tab20

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
coords = [
    (0, 0),
    (1, 2),
    (1, 3),
    (2, 2),
]

patches = [plt.Circle(coords[i], 0.1) for i in range(len(coords))]
patch_collection = PatchCollection(patches, facecolor=cmap.colors[0:num_col])
ax.add_collection(patch_collection)

ax.set_xlim(-1, 3)
ax.set_ylim(-1, 4)
plt.axis('equal')
```

Output:

[image]

This gives a random color from the selected colormap by using numpy to generate a list of random numbers, then using the patch objects `set_array` method:

```
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
coords = [
    (0, 0),
    (1, 2),
    (1, 3),
    (2, 2),
]
patches = [plt.Circle(coords[i], 0.1) for i in range(len(coords))]
color_vals = np.random.rand(len(patches))
patch_collection = PatchCollection(patches, cmap='tab20', match_original=True)
patch_collection.set_array(color_vals)
ax.add_collection(patch_collection)

ax.set_xlim(-1, 3)
ax.set_ylim(-1, 4)
plt.axis('equal')
```

Output:

[image]

I don't think `match_original=True` is necessary as you want to change the default color of the original patches. I'm sure there other ways of doing this as well. This SO post was helpful: [setting color range in matplotlib patchcollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028675/setting-color-range-in-matplotlib-patchcollection)

Comment: Some combination of these two options should cover your use case, but let me know if that is not the case, and I can update the answer.